# Help configuring display settings: Ubuntu 20.04 and old (of course) desktop w/NVIDIA GeForce 7050 graphics card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, display-resolution, monitor

I recently loaded Ubuntu 20.04 onto a new 1TB hard drive in an old eMachines desktop computer.

Info:
NVIDIA GeForce 7050 Integrated graphics card
VGA port on desktop; no other display ports
Acer 20” LCD monitor, model X203H
Monitor has a VGA port and a DVI-D port. (I’m using VGA).

I’m looking for a way to set display resolution to 1152 x 864. The GUI only offers one option - 640 x 480.

Initially, the GUI display was pretty bad. I could only work in terminal. (Problems: image tearing, tiling, background image was discolored and pixelated all over, etc. I couldn’t check display settings at first, because I couldn’t read any of the options; dialog boxes would overlay the active box if I moused over the area on screen).

So, I’ve:
. Downloaded and attempted to install the appropriate NVIDIA drivers (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.135).

. This fails, but has somehow resolved most of the problems with the GUI. The error message: “Installation has failed. Please see the file ‘var/log/NVIDIA-installer.log’ for details. The log mentions certain error codes (Error 127, Error 2, Error 1). I have yet to unravel / translate the errors.

. The drivers are partially successful, the GUI can now be used. The colors are full and rich, images and colors are stable when I mouse over them, no more tiling and very little tearing. The biggest remaining problem that I notice is that Displays | Resolution offers only one option 640 x 840 (4:3). With a 20” monitor, this means I have really large images and fonts, and I have to scroll or move dialog boxes in order to read everything in the box. Ideally, I think I need to set resolution to 1152 x 864.

. Tried xrandr, but it returns the error “Can’t open display”

. lshw -c video  command returns as part of it’s response that display is “unclaimed”

. cvt 1152 864 75   command doesn’t throw an error, but appears to have no affect.

Anyone else running in to these problems? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the NVIDIA proprietary driver may not be supported anymore for the latest kernels > 5.4

try to use instead : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

please see [After an update and reboot in Ubuntu 20.04 I can no longer complete the boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305862/after-an-update-and-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-i-can-no-longer-complete-the-boot)
and [The installation of the NVIDIA display driver 340 fails in Kubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284266/the-installation-of-the-nvidia-display-driver-340-fails-in-kubuntu-20-10)